# Write a static method which takes two strings and returns a boolean saying whether the first string occurs as a substring within the second

Tags: java, string

> Write a static method which takes two strings and returns a boolean saying whether the first string occurs as a substring within the second. For example, if the strings are `"blis"` and `"antidisestablishment"`, the method should return `true`. See if you can write two versions of the method, one using iteration, the other using recursion.

I am getting a error on the line `'if (str2.substring(j,j+str1.length()).equals(str1)){'` when I excute the program

```
class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str1 = input.nextLine();
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter another string: ");
        String str2 = input1.nextLine();
        if (q2(str1,str2)) {
             System.out.println(str1 + " is , a substring of " + str2);
        } else { 
            System.out.println(str1 + " is not, a substring of " + str2);
        }

    }

    public static boolean q2(String str1, String str2) {
        boolean word = false; 
        for(int i =0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            for(int j =0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                if (str2.substring(j,j+str1.length()).equals(str1)){
                    word = true;
                } else {
                    word = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
}
```

Comment: _What does the error say?_

Comment: Hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just iterate through the longer string, and check all subtrings of length str1.length() against str1.

```
public static boolean q2(String str1, String str2) {

        for(int i = 0; i <= str2.length()-str1.length(); i++) {
            String sub = str2.substring(i, i+str1.length());
            if (sub.equals(str1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The recursive version is very easy to implement, I'll leave that as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkSubString(String a,String b){
        return b.contains(a);
}
```